# Swift NSDictionary get 0th value without knowing key name

Tags: ios, swift

I have an NSDictionary that has a key like `messageID5` and the value has three key/value pairs.

I know the NSDictionary only has 1 value in it because I limited my query to 1. But I don't know the name of the key. I just want the value, but I can't access it like an array [0]. You can access it just fine in PHP or Python. I've been trying a lot of different solutions for this basic problem, but a lot of them seem overly messy. anyValue[0] gives me a type error.

Comment: just get its keys.first property. If your dictionary is NSDictionary `dict.allKeys.first`

Comment: I think there may be Keys and Items properties, which return simple lists.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks, I'm still getting an error. I should mention that the value itself is another NSDictionary, I'm getting a type error trying to cast a __NSCFString into NSDictionary

Comment: Are you trying to convert the key itself ? try `dict[dict.allKeys.first] as? [String: Any] ?? [:]`

Comment: @LeoDabus Nah I'm being dumb. I think this solves my problem. Previously I failed with `dict.allValues[0]`. I can accept that answer.

Comment: @ScriptKitty You should use Swift native Dictionary type `[String: Any]` unless you have no choice.

Comment: @LeoDabus Oh no when I was entering test data I dropped in a string instead of an object (Firebase won't let you manually add in objects). In production they're all guaranteed to be objects. Thanks anyway

Comment: Why are you using `NSDictionary` objects rather than native Swift `Dictionary` objects?

Comment: @Duncan C idk ill look into it. Thats just how they do it in firebase docs lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't know your dictionary keys, you can get your NSDictionary allKeys.first property  or  allValues.first:

```
let dict = NSDictionary(dictionary: ["a":["b":1]])

let subDict = dict[dict.allKeys.first] as? [String:Any] ?? [:]     // ["b": 1]
// or
let subDict = dict.allValues.first as? [String:Any] ?? [:]         // ["b": 1]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just `.keys` in Swift 3, and that `allKeys` is no longer supported.. you could either use `dict[dict.keys.first]` or `dict.values.first`. `dict.values.first` seems simpler.

Comment: @DuncanC He is using NSDictionary not Swift Dictionary. BTW I am using Xcode 8.3.1 Swift 3.1

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to acknowledge is that key/value pairs in dictionaries does not maintain any specific order - this is required for an optimization in access to the contents of this structure.

As for your case if you're 100% sure you'll have only one value inside your dictionary you can use `.allValues.first` to retrieve the contained value. If your know that the type of your value is `NSDictionary` the whole code may look like this:

```
let childDictionary = rootDictionary.allValues.first as? NSDictionary
```

Comment: Thanks dude but this doesn't really add to what Leo said.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `(dictionary as Dictionary).values.first`. That returns an optional, since it can fail if the dictionary is empty.

(Note that I edited this answer to cast the dictionary from an `NSDictionary` to a `Dictionary` so you an use the `values` property. `NSDictionary` doesn't have a values property, but `Dictionary` does.)

Comment: NSDictionary has no values property

Comment: You're right, I missed the fact that this was an NSDictionary. Can't you cast to Dictionary and use the values property though?

Comment: Why would you cast to Dictionary to use values if NSDictionary already have the allValues property that does exactly the same? BTW You can try the code in my answer with an empty dictionary, it also deals with the optionals and returns a native Swift Dictionary

Comment: Yes, since the OP is using an NSDictionary staying with Foundation objects probably makes more sense. Your second allValues option is probably the better answer.